# What's the difference between mail.smtp.auth and mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication in Javamail/Spring

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm using Spring 3.1.0 to send email using the JavaMailSenderImpl class.
Here is my Spring config xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="your.mail.server"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="smtp"/>
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">5000</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.sendpartial">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.userset">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.isSecure">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">25</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

To be honest I'm not sure where I got all this from, probably some sample code I got from a tutorial sometime.

I want to turn off SMTP authentication and I can see from the [JavaMail docs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) that I need to set the **mail.smtp.auth** property to false. But in my config xml I also set a property called **mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication** that from the name seems equally relevant, but I can't find any reference to it in the JavaMail or Spring documentation. Google does however find lots of examples of it being used.

Is **mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication** actually needed and if so what does it do? Could it be a deprecated, or even bogus, property?

Answer (score 0):

You really should understand the code before you do cut&paste...

There is no mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication property in JavaMail.

I don't know anything about how Spring uses JavaMail, but in JavaMail if you don't want to do authentication, don't call the connect method that provides a username and password, or pass the username and password as null with mail.smtp.auth set to false.  If you call connect with username or password not null, it doesn't matter what mail.smtp.auth is set to.

Comment: I thought I did understand the code, though my assumptions may have been wrong and more due diligence may be required. A quick google on  "mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication" shows that I'm not the only one and it would be good to confirm that this is in fact a bogus property for others that come here with the same question. Maybe it's a Spring thing  that tries to handle different implementations of JavaMail.